# ng-directive to help filter elements according to page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm a super junior developer at the moment, and I keep getting tripped up on directives and controllers.

I am wanting to write a ng-if or hide/show controller that will show element according to page. Ex: Nav bar information is pretty minimal, but when you are on a page, you'll see what could be described as (though not really) a pill or breadcrumb.

HTML

```
<!-- within bootstrap nav --> <div class="row col-md-4 text-center" ng-if="location.path === '/a_scientist'"><p class="opener"><em><span class="purple">/TRAINED SCIENTIST </span></em></p></div>
```

I've been able to do this using User Roles, but there is no passport in this project. Can anyone help with this?